# Star rating system calculation

Tags: php

I am creating a simple rating system for my ecommerce. I have a review page and in the form the user can rate the product from 1-5. I can save already the rate but I don't know how can I compute this. Here's my sample data.

```
Array
(
    [rate_1] => 0 // total user voted for rate 'boo'
    [rate_2] => 1 // total user voted for rate 'more improvement'
    [rate_3] => 0 // total user voted for rate 'its ok'
    [rate_4] => 2 // total user voted for rate 'i recommend this'
    [rate_5] => 4 // total user voted for rate 'i highly recommend this'
)
```

Here's a simple graph:

```
rate_1 = Boo
rate_2 = More Improvement
rate_3 = It's OK
rate_4 = I recommend this
rate_5 = I highly recommend this
```

What I want is to get the percentage for every rate. What is the percentage rate for selection 'Boo', etc etc..

And lastly get the summary percentage for all of this.

The reason for getting the percentage for every rate is I want to create a progress rate like to one in the Google Playstore.

Comment: yes, in my database  i can save how many users voted in a specific rate. But what I need also is to get their percantage every rate and get the total summary percentage of all rates.

Comment: it's the result generate from my php through my databasr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this use `array_sum` if you want to do through array

```
($your_array_name['rate_1']/array_sum($your_array_name))*100;
```

**value explanation**

`$your_array_name['rate_1']` **==** Number of vote caste for **rate_1**

`array_sum($your_array_name)`**==** This will produce the total number of votes. If you already have total for votes. just simply replace `array_sum($your_array_name)` with **Total Votes**

Comment: in my rate_5 I already have a total of 4 so it means `(4/array_sum(rate_5)) * 100`?

Comment: This process is for getting the individual rate percentage or overall?

Answer (score 1):

In database you can save total rating and how much users has voted.
Than just calculate rating:

```
$perProduct = product.totalRating / product.totalVotes
$totalRatingOfProduct = product.totalRating / SUM(product.totalVotes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `N` be the total number of ratings given on a single product.

For your sample data here :

```
Array
(
    [rate_1] => 0 // total user voted for rate 'boo'
    [rate_2] => 1 // total user voted for rate 'more improvement'
    [rate_3] => 0 // total user voted for rate 'its ok'
    [rate_4] => 2 // total user voted for rate 'i recommend this'
    [rate_5] => 4 // total user voted for rate 'i highly recommend this'
)
```

`N` would be `0+1+0+2+4 == 7`

Percentage for rate_1 (Boo) would be `(votesOfRate1/N)*100`

So the number of users who voted **Boo** would be `(0/7)*100`, which is **0%**.

Percentage for rate_2 (More Improvement) would be `(votesOfRate2/N)*100`

So the number of users who voted **More Improvement** would be `(1/7)*100`, which is **14.29%**.

And so on.

If you want to compute the average rating for a single product, do a weighted sum average :

`AverageRating = ((1*votesOfRate1)+(2*votesOfRate2)+(3*votesOfRate3)+(4*votesOfRate4)+(5*votesOfRate5))/N`

Comment: Thanks I will try. It will help me a lot. :)

Comment: Yes, `N` is the total number of votes on a single product regardless of rating.

Comment: `votesOfRate1` should be the number of votes on the **Boo** option, not the total.

Comment: you mean if I have a rate of 1 to 5 then the value of Boo is 1 then highly recommend is 5?

Comment: @Jerielle, check my edited answer. Hopefully you would understand better with examples. Cheers.